# Inheritance PHP, passing methods and using children's properties instead of parent's ones

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, methods

Why does parent's method getHC() passed to Professeur refers to $this->quota of parent (Enseignant) instead of children's $this->quota.

```
abstract class Enseignant {

  private $quota; //empty

  public function __construct($nom, $nbHeures)[...]

  public function getHC(){
     return $this->nbHeures - $this->quota; //Ici le problème
  }

  abstract protected function setQuota($q);
}
```

I need $this->nbHeures - $this->quota to be pass to Professeur

```
class Professeur extends Enseignant {
        const QUOTA = 192;

        public function __construct($nom, $nbHeures) {
            parent::__construct($nom, $nbHeures);
            $this->setQuota(self::QUOTA);
        }

        protected function setQuota($q) {
            $this->quota = $q;
        }
}
```

And use Professeur's quota and not Enseignant's one.

Comment: $e = new Professeur("Charles", 292);
    echo $e->getHC();

Should give me 100 not 292...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two problems with your sample code:

1. Your `Professeur` class does not extend the `Enseignant` class. I'm not sure if this is just a typo as you copied in your sample code - but the second class should be declared as:

   ```
   class Professeur extends Enseignant {
   ```
2. The `$quota` member variable is declared as private in the parent class. This means that the child class cannot access the value and the `setQuota()` function in the child class is instead setting a new (undeclared) variable with the same name on the child class.

   To fix this, you should declare the `$quota` variable as `protected` instead of `private`.

   ```
   protected $quota;
   ```

The following code should work more like what you're expecting:

```
abstract class Enseignant {
    protected $quota; // declare as protected so it can be
                      // accessed and modified from the child class

    public function __construct($nom, $nbHeures) {
        $this->nbHeures = $nbHeures;
    }

    public function getHC() {
        return $this->nbHeures - $this->quota;
    }

    abstract protected function setQuota($q);
}

class Professeur extends Enseignant {
    const QUOTA = 192;

    public function __construct($nom, $nbHeures) {
        parent::__construct($nom, $nbHeures);
        $this->setQuota(self::QUOTA);
    }

    protected function setQuota($q) {
        $this->quota = $q;
    }
}

$e = new Professeur("Charles", 292);
echo $e->getHC(); // returns 100 now
```

An alternate solution would be to leave the `$quota` variable as private, and make the `setQuota()` method part of the parent class - still calling it from the child constructor.

Comment: fixed that, it is extended. Looking up for $quota.

Comment: so how could I use the right $quota? I changed it to protected and it didn't work.

Comment: I've updated with your example rewritten to what I think you're looking for. Does that help?

Comment: Lovely and detailed. +1!